# Python: Assert a UserWarning

Tags: python, python-unittest

I created my own python script `script.py` in which I define my own class (e.g. `myclass`). The class reads a csv file as a dataframe. One of the checks that I established is for making sure that a specific column exists in the dataset. The check is:

```
if ("column" not in self.df.columns): warnings.warn("column is not available in the input file.")
```

This actually works fine and when the `"column"` is not included in the dataset, the warning error is produced:

```
UserWarning: column is not available in the input file.
  if ("column" not in self.df.columns): warnings.warn("column is not available in the input file.")
```

I am trying to verify/assert the issue of the warning message by running the following unit test:

```
import script
...
...
...
def test_if_error_is_issued ():
    with pytest.raises(UserWarning) as warn:
        script.myclass(path)
```

I think that the latter code chunk is not correct as I keep receiving the following error message ( `path` actually leads to a csv without the "column"):

```
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'UserWarning'>
```

Comment: Use `pytest.warns` instead of `pytest.raises`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Smooth :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MrBean Bremen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12480730/mrbean-bremen) answered this question.

The solution is to change `pytest.raises` to `pytest.warns`.